# How to electronically disconnect two way data line

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, signal, buffer

I have a SPI data line which dynamically is switched by several microcontrollers between MOSI and MISO mode, i.e. only one physical wire is used for two way communication. The micros take turns which one to use the line based on a protocol logic.

I need to switch one of the micros off the line, like physically disconnect it so the line is in high impedance and the other communication can go on undisturbed.

I tried with a tri-state buffer 74HC125, but it is only one way communication. Connecting two 74HC125 buffers "in circle" - A to B and B to A doesn't work. The line is always pulled low by the IC and not left in Z state.

I tried with a 74HC245 two-way transceiver, but still no success: I can switch directions from A to B and from B to A but only one at a time, and I need a full time two way connection when not in Z state. The stated "Latch A=B" mode in the [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/SN74LS243) does not work - the line is pulled low all the time by the IC.

So to recap: 
I need to have a full time two-way communication line which can be switched to a high impedance mode electronically.

What would be the way to achieve this?

Comment: Use the search term "FET bus switch" and I think you will find what you need. These are not really buffers. They just use bidirectional FET switches to disconnect or connect busses together.

Comment: @mkeith I looked for it. Sounds like the right IC. Will test it. Thanks!